# How to listen to HTTP requests and a serial channel in the same Python program?

Tags: python, webserver, serial-port, arduino, xml-rpc

I have an Arduino board connected to my PC's serial port. The board sends data to the PC, but it can also receive orders by the same channel. However, there is no relation or sequence between the sent data and the orders.

In the PC, I have created a daemon that listens on the serial port. And for sending data to the Arduino I was thinking of establishing an XML RPC server within the daemon. The problem is I don't know how to listen to the serial port and attend XML RPC request in the same program.

Initially, I had something like this in my mind:

```
while true
    if there is incoming data in the serial channel
       blah blah

    if there are HTTP requests
        start attending the XML RPC request
```

The servers I've been looking at (SimpleXMLRPCServer, web.py) are listening and handling requests all the time. I would like to tell to my XML RPC server "wait, if there are no requests we are going to check the serial channel".

How can I achieve that or something similar? Or should I change my design? If I have the XML RPC server in another process I think I would need some kind of interprocess communication which is why I started using XML RPC in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use what is called a program with threads. It allows to do several actions in parallel.

If you use Python, you have more information here: http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#thread-objects

However threads can be hard to graps and to correctly use. There are several tutorial on threading an Python, do not hesitate to check them with a search engine.

The big idea is to do something like that:

```
import threading

def processCommands():
    while True:
        #wait and process commands

def readSerial():
    while True:
        #read serial

serialThread = threading.Thread(target=readSerial)
commandThread = threading.Thread(target=processCommands)
serialThread.start()
commandThread.start()

#Wait for the command thread to exit,
#otherwise the programs would immediately exit
commandThread.join()
```

Comment: I used this approach because it was more general. Next time I will give a shot to twisted since I have heard a lot of good things about it. if you're interested the code is here: [vr-domotic](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vr-domotic/)

Answer (score 2):

Another (and probably better) approach is to migrate application to asynchronous [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output). For example you can use a twisted framework (like, [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/)) to handle both [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) and serial traffic simultaneously asynchronously in two separate protocol handlers.

Something like that:

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from twisted.internet.serialport import SerialPort

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class HttpResource(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def render_GET(self, request):
        request.setHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
        return "Hello there\n"

reactor.listenTCP(8080, server.Site(HttpResource()))
SerialPort(Echo(), <your serial port>, reactor, baudrate=9600)

reactor.run()
```

Comment: +1 for Twisted, this is clearly a framework created for this purpose